# Encoded json gets corrupted/escaped by PostgresQL?

Tags: php, json, postgresql, yii2

I am using a Yii2 model that is hooked to a PostgresQL database. I have a behavior that encodes and decodes certain attributes of this model to/from json. To encode/decode, I am using the Json helper, the `Json::encode` and `Json::decode` methods.

The column in the table is of a json type. An example of what ends up in the database:

```
"{\"additional_tags\":[\"#здрасте\",\"#кафе\"],\"vk\":\"vk.com\\\/privetik\"}"
```

When I try to decode it back into a php array, here's what's returned instead:

```
'{"additional_tags":["#здрасте","#кафе"],"vk":"vk.com\/privetik"}'
```

EDIT: Come to think of it, the string seems fine, but the behavior of the `::decode` method is strange. Essentially, all it does is remove the escape slashes, instead of converting it into a php array or throwing an exception.

What should I do to fix this? Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Looks okay to me. What are you *expecting* to be returned?

Comment: A php array, or an exception. Actually, now that I pasted into a jsonlint, it seems fine. But still, it's a very weird behavior for the `::decode` method to give me a string instead of an array (yes, I pass that second parameter).

Comment: Please be a lot more detailed about how you pass what to what and decode what when where and how you output what value when how. It's completely unclear what exactly you're doing and what values are escaped when. It's not even clear whether some of the escaping is only for debugging display or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the string in your database is encoded twice. Try passing it through `Json::decode` another time, I bet it will return your array.

Comment: Yeah, essentially this was the case. What happened is that I had the encode being done twice because I've assigned it to be done on nearly all of the ActiveRecord events while in reality I needed only a few of those.